# How to access data from models in view in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So I have a models file:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models

class Organization(models.Model):
    name           = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True);
    description    = models.TextField(blank=True);
    location       = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True);
    contact_email  = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique=True);
    org_type       = models.ForeignKey('OrganizationType');
    created_at     = models.DateTimeField(editable=False);
    updated_at     = models.DateTimeField();

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' On save, update timestamps '''
    datetime_now = datetime.datetime.now();

    # If there's no ID, it's new
    if not self.id:
        self.created_at = datetime_now;

    # Always update the modified at value
    self.modified_at = datetime_now;

    return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs);

class Meta:
    app_label = 'bc';
```

And a view file Organization.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

from BearClubs.bc.forms.user import UserSignUpForm
from BearClubs.bc.models.organization import Organization

def directory(request):
    first_50_clubs = [];

    # get 50 clubs here

return render(request, 'directory.html' {'clubs': first_50_clubs});
```

I am really new to Django so pardon me. How do I go about getting the first 50 clubs in the first_50_clubs in the Organization.py view file?

Answer (score 9):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets), you can just use list slicing:

> Use a subset of Python’s array-slicing syntax to limit your QuerySet
>   to a certain number of results. This is the equivalent of SQL’s LIMIT
>   and OFFSET clauses.

```
def directory(request):
    first_50_clubs = Organization.objects.all()[:50]

    return render(request, 'directory.html' {'clubs': first_50_clubs})
```

Also, you don't need to put semi-colons at the end of code lines in python.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can get **first 50 clubs** in the first_50_clubs by following query :

```
first_50_clubs = Organization.objects.all().order_by('id')[:50]
```

It will fetch records when its got inserted .

If you want **last inserted 50** records then just use `-` in `order_by` . like :

```
first_50_clubs = Organization.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:50]
```